# Python | NumPy | Coordinates - An issue with conversion of geographical coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, coordinates, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I have a pretty simple issue: I need to convert the file with geographical coordinates like

```
Lat         Long
50 0 50     35 1 40
50 2 50     35 10 20
50 3 1      35 13 22
50 2 38     35 14 40
49 59 6     35 13 22
49 57 14    35 13 21
49 57 10    35 13 0
49 57 0     35 6 20
```

to the

```
Lat      Long
50.01389,35.02778
50.04722,35.17222
etc.
```

Math is as simple as a pie: we have to devide minutes (0 and 1 in this particular case) by 60 and seconds (50 and 40) by 3600, then add these numbers and we will get the remainder of the degree (50 and 35).

Here is my script with numpy. I suppose, it looks to big for such a simple conversion, however I don't know how to do this simpler. Also I don't know how to end this script, so it could do what it should. Now it ends with adding minutes and seconds.

```
import sys
import numpy as np


filename = input('Please enter the file\'s name: ')
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    sys.stdout = open('%s (converted).txt' % f.name, 'a')

    data = np.loadtxt(f)
    degree_lat, degree_long = data[:, 0], data[:, 3]
    min_lat, sec_lat, min_long, sec_long = \
        (data[:, 1] / 60), (data[:, 2] / 3600), (data[:, 4] / 60), (data[:, 5] / 3600)

    remainder_lat, remainder_long = min_lat + sec_lat, min_long + sec_long

    degree_result_lat = degree_lat + remainder_lat
    degree_result_long = degree_long + remainder_long
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks and sorry for the amateur questions.

Comment: Can you post a few example lines of your input file? Also what are you trying to achieve with `sys.stdout = open...`?

Comment: Is this a question about how to optimize/minimize your code? You might want to check out [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) then.

Comment: @NilsWerner I have just updated this topic. You can find an example of the input file in the top of it.

Comment: @OliverW. Thanks for the link, I will)

Comment: That script and the data you provided do not run, it fails with `ValueError: could not convert string to float: Lat`.

Comment: @NilsWerner I have just tried it in PyCharm - it works, prints degree_result_lat and degree_result_long as 2 ndarrays. Have also substituted with the code from the PyCharm - try please one more time)

Comment: Both Python 2 and 3 fail with `ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'Lat'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you have in `data` array,

```
data = data.T # not strictly necessary, but simplifies following indexing

lat = data[0]+data[1]/60.+data[2]/3600.
lon = data[3]+data[4]/60.+data[5]/3600.

converted = np.vstack((lat,lon)).T

np.savetxt(outname, converted)
```

---

Line by line comment

1. `data.T` transposes the array, columns becomes tows and in Python it's easier to address rows than columns...
2. `data[0]+data[1]/60.+data[2]/3600.` is a *vectorized* expression, each row of the `data` array is an array on its own, and you can evaluate algebraic expressions, possibly using also `numpy`'s functions that accept, as arguments, vector expressions as well.
3. as above…
4. `np.vstack((lat,lon)).T` we have two names that reference two different expressions, we want to combine them in a single array, so that we can use `np.savetxt()` to save it.
   Using `np.vstack()` we get an array like

   ```
   [[lt0, lt1, ..., ltN],
    [ln0, ln1, ..., lnN]]
   ```

   but we want to save an array like

   ```
   [[lt0, ln0],
    [lt1, ln1],
    ...
   ```

   so we have to transpose the result of `np.vstack()`
5. `np.savetxt(outname, converted)` we save at once the whole array using one of the convenient conveniency functions offered by the `numpy` libraries.

Note that, when using `numpy` you should try to avoid explicit loops and instead relying on its ability to *vectorize* most expressions. This leads to much more efficient code.

Comment: Thank you, this works as well) I didn't know about ".T", it seems to a pretty usefull option.

Comment: It works better, because 1. you avoid the overload connected to the execution of explicit loops in an interpreted language and 2. the output file is properly formatted, and can be loaded by `np.loadtxt()`.

Comment: Wow, many thanks for the very detailed answer, for the vectorizing and others. I will try to do my work in more Pythonic way and get rid of the loops. For now, this looks even more simpler)

Comment: I think that this is redundant, but I'd like anyway to stress that it's only `numpy` and the use of its arrays that allows you to avoid explicit loops... it doesn't work with ordinary Python's lists.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a more Pythonic way as follows.

```
import numpy as np
f = open('data.txt','r')
data = np.loadtxt(f)
coords = [(el[:3],el[3:]) for el in data]
print coords
output = [(c[0][0]+c[0][1]/60.+c[0][2]/3600.,c[1][0]+c[1][1]/60.+c[1][2]/3600.) for c in coords]
print output
```

Output :

```
[(50.013888888888886, 35.027777777777779),
 (50.047222222222217, 35.172222222222217),
 (50.050277777777772, 35.222777777777779),
 (50.043888888888887, 35.244444444444447),
 (49.984999999999999, 35.222777777777779),
 (49.953888888888891, 35.222500000000004),
 (49.952777777777783, 35.216666666666669),
 (49.950000000000003, 35.105555555555554)]
```

**Explanation**

`Line 4`: Loads the co-ordinates in `coords` as `tuple`s
`Line 5`: For each co-ordinate in `coords` calculates the co-ordinate in decimal system and assigns them to `output` as `tuple`s

Comment: Abdul, great, thanks for the more Pythonic result and explanation)

Comment: By the way, how can I get rid of the tuple in the output file? I tries to use the for-loop and .join but it didn't help. Is there any simple option?